# Copy word table to a new word file

Tags: ms-word, copy, word-table

My question may be stupid, but I'm not that good at Microsoft Word to solve that problem by myself. I tried some solutions, ofc not every, cause I have no time.

My problem is may be simple: I can't copy some M. Word tables to a new M. Word file, but there's one issue: the tables that I want to copy is just done bad (I guess), like it made for no copy...

Here is the file: https://gofile.io/d/09vnQf. First example is on 90'th page.
This problem tables looks like this in the end: [Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pCdb.png).

I can't copy the only tables with that end. The format of this tables are just
like goes wild. What should I do?

Comment: Your file contains pictures. More exactly, there is no text in your file, just pictures of pages. At least, this is the case for page 90. I tried to save the picture in a separate file using the right-click menu but it seems that the picture is only the drawing and all text is on a different level. Normal copy/paste won't work in this case.

Comment: Thank you for response, but do you have any ideas how to copy this together?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Unfortunately, you may not receive an answer here and your question may be closed without one because it is off-topic.  This is a forum about programming, not about using applications like Word.https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic It would be fine in the SuperUser forum. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word